# Session reverts to its original value on my production server, but not my local server

Tags: php, session

I'm creating a quick website to host a survey I'm doing for a class. I have 12 different audio clips that I'd like to play. The user is given a choice between two different clips, and each clip is presented only once. I'm using an array stored in a session variable to keep track of which clips have already been played. On localhost, this works flawlessly. But on a production server, the session seems to revert to its original value.

```
<?php

echo "Beginning session: " . implode(' ', $_SESSION['clip_ids']) . "<br>";

if(empty($_SESSION['clip_ids'])) {
    $_SESSION['clip_ids'] = range(0,11);
    header('Location: survey2.php');
    exit;
}

$clips = array( /*names of 12 audio files here */ );

$i = -1;
$j = -1;

while(!in_array($i, $_SESSION['clip_ids'])) {
    $i = rand(0,11);
}

while(!in_array($j, $_SESSION['clip_ids']) || $j == $i) {
    $j = rand(0,11);
}

unset($_SESSION['clip_ids'][$i]);
unset($_SESSION['clip_ids'][$j]);

echo "Ending session: " . implode(' ', $_SESSION['clip_ids']) . "<br>";

?>
```

On my localhost server, the beginning session lists the numbers 0-11, and the end session list 0-11 with two numbers removed. Upon refreshing the page, the beginning session lists the previous end session, the end session list the previous end session with two more numbers removed, and so on.

On my production server, the beginning session lists the numbers 0-11, and the end session list 0-11 with two numbers removed, just as expected. It would seem that $_SESSION['clip_ids'] was successfully set to the range, minus two numbers. But upon refreshing the page, the beginning session again list the numbers 0-11, and the end session lists 0-11 with two numbers removed, as if $_SESSION['clip_ids'] was never modified.

EDIT: So when I commented out the initial session assignment on my index.php page, some really weird things started happening (e.g. the array in the session would be set to empty), so I renamed my index.php to something different... and my program started behaving as I originally expected. I have no idea what the cause of this is. Any help?

Comment: Just checking, as it's not in your code, but are you calling `session_start()` at the beginning of every page?

Comment: Yeah, `session_start()` is called at the very beginning of every page.